# React + Redux. Connect выдает 'Object is not a function'

Tags: reactjs, redux

Пытаюсь подсунуть redux в свое небольшое приложение на react'е. Решил начать с малого, чтобы получить доступ к тестовым данным. Однако, что-то пошло не так.

Создаю reducer в файле **authorsReducer**:

```
export default function() {
  return [
    {
      id: 1,
      first_name: "some_username_1",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      first_name: "some_username_2",
    }
  ];
}
```

Далее создаю один большой объект со всеми reducer'ами (пусть у меня он пока единственный):

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import AuthorsReducer from './authorsReducer';

const allReducers = combineReducers({
  authors_test: AuthorsReducer
});

export default allReducers;
```

Далее, создаю store в компоненте, где я хочу отобразить свои тестовые данные:

```
...
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import allReducers from '../../reducers'
import TestContainer from '../../containers/testContainer'
const store = createStore(allReducers);
...
<Provider store={store}>
  <TestContainer />
</Provider>
```

Здесь у меня есть компонент - TestContainer, в который я хочу передать store и вывести данные, поэтому:

```
import React from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class TestContainer extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <span>Test</span>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    authors_test: state.authors_test
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TestContainer);
```

В данный момент, я даже данные не пытаюсь вывести, а просто хотя бы слово Test. Однако, консоль выдает ошибку:

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

***Наверное, важно***:

1. Если заменить строку `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TestContainer);` на `export default TestContainer;`, то ошибок не будет, но и store'a тоже =)
2. Если в третьем файле распечатать в консоль `store.getState()`, то все данные видны

Что не нравится connect'у?

**P.S.** тут, на SO.ru нашлась пара похожих тем, но что-то там дальше комментариев дело не пошло. Попытался дать детали структуры, чтобы получить помощь.

Comment: Я скопипастил ваш код в codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/wy94pr4wkl  - он вполне рабочий. Скорее всего вы или код не тот привели, или просто где-то файл не сохранили. Смотрите в консоли stack trace ошибки - оно же в конкретном месте падает.

Comment: @PashaPash вы правы, я указал не весь код, но хотел оставить лишь минимальный пример. Ведь так же удобнее разбирать проблему =) Однако, я создал новое небольшое приложение локально, скопировав весь ваш код из codesandbox, но с моим package.json. И оно выдало ту же ошибку. Тогда я обновил версии пакетов и ура, минимальный пример запустился. Сейчас попробую на живом приложении